# Are negative answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion, statistics

There are many, many unanswered questions asking if features exist or if certain behaviors are possible.

For cases where features don't (yet) exist, but have plans to add them or such promising information, I'll add a comment. If there is a working patch or some way to get the desired behavior/result, I'll add an answer.

However, if there are no plans (that I know about) to add such features, I just leave it.
It seems to me that most other users are doing pretty much the same things.

Since having a lot of unanswered questions is not good for our stats, should we start answering these questions with "*no, xy isn't possible atm*"? Or will this not really help as such answers don't seem likely to be upvoted or accepted?

How should we handle these questions?

Comment: Related, http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/177/12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, negative answers are good, often users are unsure if some feature exists for their workflow. And if there is no way to accomplish the tasks its best to say so, And possibly suggest workarounds if they exist.

It's useful to know the limitation of technologies you use as well as the features.

---

*In my own experience asking questions, I've noticed people often attempt to answer questions which solutions you wouldn't realistically use, personally I would rather a straight answer if something isn't supported.*

Comment: That is it exactly. +1